# I need to merge three where condition in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to merger three queries ans show in one table structure

Sql query:

```
 SELECT MonthName(created) as Month ,year(created) as Year ,user_type,count(user_type) 
   FROM `cii_registered_users` 
  WHERE verification=1 
    AND activation_step=5 
    AND status=1 
    AND user_type='1' 
    AND year(created)='2017'  
    AND created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH   
  GROUP BY user_type,month(created),year(created)
```

```
  SELECT MonthName(created) as Month ,year(created) as Year ,user_type,count(user_type) 
    FROM `cii_registered_users` 
   WHERE verification=1 
     AND activation_step=5 
     AND status=1 
     AND user_type='2' 
     AND year(created)='2017'  
     AND created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH   
   GROUP BY user_type,month(created),year(created)
```

```
SELECT MonthName(created) as Month ,year(created) as Year ,user_type,count(user_type) 
  FROM `cii_registered_users` 
 WHERE verification=1 
   AND activation_step=5 
   AND status=1 
   AND user_type='3' 
   AND year(created)='2017'  
   AND created > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH   
 GROUP BY user_type,month(created),year(created)
```

And then I need separate row shows all the counts of user type and total counts except three interval and total count

```
  Month     Year    count(user_type=2)      count(user_type=1)   full year count
  June      2017     12                      3
  July      2017     1                       17
  August    2017     10                      8
  September 2017     1                       1
```

I need total count in another column except this four months

Comment: What have you tried, and what is your problem?

Comment: I need two mere three sql query in single if it possible to achieve this

Comment: what is the diff in these 3 queries? I do not see it

Comment: In where condition user type is 1,2,3,4..like this but i need to merge the three query

Comment: Notice that these three queries (now) differ only in the line `AND user_type = something`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a job for a pivoting sort of query

Try something like this:

```
 SELECT MONTH(created) as Month,
        YEAR(created) as Year,
        SUM(user_type = '1') user_type_1,
        SUM(user_type = '2') user_type_2,
        SUM(user_type = '3') user_type_3
   FROM table
  WHERE whatever
  GROUP BY MONTH(created), YEAR(created)
```

Why does this work?  Because, in MySQL, expressions like `user_type = '1'` have the number value `1` if true and `0` if false.

Why is it a good way to go? It's not hard to read and verify, nor is it hard to change when needed.

If it were my query, I'd [use `LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) instead of `YEAR()` and `MONTH()`, as follows. But maybe that's just a personal preference.

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(created) AS month_ending,
          ...
 GROUP BY LAST_DAY(created)
```

Comment: Thanq before total count is taken in one row if it possible to get it..like

Comment: total count numbers in one column

Comment: @VallavanJ Please don't misuse Stack Overflow as a chat system. It's not. It's also not a code-writing service. I answered the question you asked, then you added something to your question. For best results figure out how to apply what you've learned to your problem, then try to work out how to add the other columns you need. If you can't figure it out ask another question.

Comment: I am not doing like that we need increase our result with multiple way to finding it ..thanks for answering